# Objective-C Category import strange behavior

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, import, categories

I am extending a class from a external library. Here is my code:

Header file: Manager+MyCategory.h

```
#import "Manager.h"
#import "Element.h"

@interface Manager (myCategory) 
- (Element*) elementWithTag:(NSInteger)tag; 
@end
```

Implementation file: Manager+MyCategory.h file

```
@implementation Manager (myCategory) 

- (Element*) elementWithTag:(NSInteger)tag {
    ...
}

@end
```

Now here is how I use this category:

```
#import "Manager+MyCategory.h"

@implementation myClass 

- (void) myFunction:(NSInteger)tag {
   Manager* myManager = [[Manager alloc] init];
   Element* = [myManager elementWithTag:tag];

   ...

   [myManager release];
}

@end
```

When I compile I have no warnings but when I run my program I get the following error:

```
*** -[Manager elementWithTag:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105d9a0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[Manager elementWithTag:]:
```

Header file (ie Manager+MyCategory.h) is correctly imported but it looks like the link with the implementation file is not done. 
If I replace #import "Manager+MyCategory**.h**" by #import "Manager+MyCategory**.m**" in my class it's working properly.

Anyone can explain me what I forgot? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Categories do not work well with traditional Unix **static** libraries.

If that's your case, it seems that passing the -ObjC option to the linker resolves the issue.

[Apple Technical Q&A QA1490](http://developer.apple.com/qa/qa2006/qa1490.html) explains it all.

Comment: Thanks! 
Just add -ObjC linker flag to my project and it works properly

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you have forgotten to add the Manager+MyCategory.m to the approrpriate target in Xcode. You do not get a linker error because all the symbols exist and there is no compiler warning because you have included the appropriate header files, but at runtime the implementation of the `elementWithTag:` method is missing.

Comment: Good point! but I checked and Manager+MyCategory.m is well in the target compile sources. Thx anyway

Comment: Another sanity check never hurt. Try throwing a #error in your Manager+MyCategory.m. If the compiler doesn't fail, you know for sure your category isn't getting compiled.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help. I'll leave the answer here because it may help someone else in the future. Good luck.

Comment: @kperryua Tried throwing an exception in Manager+MyCategory.m and nothing happened. My category is definitely not compiled. Now let's find why. Thanks for your help

Comment: This was my problem, and including the .m file fixed the error. Didn't think to look there though...

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, could not add this as a comment...

Just for testing, you may want to add an extern c function declared in the header and implemented in the .m file.  If you call this c function within your test code then this **will** generate a linker error due to an unresolved identifier.

This can make it easier to investigate the problem as it provides immediate feedback and may generate some additional clues as to why the file is not being included.

Given the time frame, I'll assume you've done this, but just in case... make sure that you've cleaned the target, shut down XCode, and then re-open.  I've had the project files become corrupted in memory and act strangely.

Barney

Comment: Ooooh!! Something interesting happened (even though I don't think the work "interesting" is approriate :) ).
I added an extern c function in my category header and implemented in the .m file. I called it within my test code and, guess what, everything works properly: external function is called as well as the "elementWithTag" method.
I don't understand anything and going nuts.

Of course I cleaned the target, close and re-open XCode.

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: I forgot to mention that if I remove the extern C function it's not working anymore.

Comment: That is quite interesting.  Have you tried adjusting the linker settings, such as disabling "Dead Code Stripping".  I suspect this is some sort of flaw in the linker optimization.  It would be a good idea to open a bug report with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when upgrading to Xcode 4.

To fix I had to separate my category definition into a separate .m and a .h - Xcode 3 seemed okay with the implementation and interface being in a .h ... but oh no fussy Xcode 4 is rather anal.