# Categories & singelton in cocoa

Tags: cocoa, xcode, singleton, categories

I have a SingletonClass, which has only one instance. I want to expand it and add to it a category (MoreFeatures).

I created a source SingletonClass+MoreFeatures, which interface/implementation looks like that:

```
@interface SingletonClass (MoreFeatures)

- (void) feature;

@end

@implementation SingletonClass (MoreFeatures)
- (void) feature
{
}
@end
```

When I created my SingletonClass i followed the Apple's example of Singleton implementation in cocoa.

This singleton resides in a project B, which is a dependency of a bigger project A.
I can call for `[[SingletonClass sharedInstance] foo]` from a source in project A and it works in case that function foo is located in SingletonClass interface/implementation. When I try to call `[[SingletonClass sharedInstance] feature]` from a source in project A, I get a crash, which says that there is no method feature for class SingletonClass...

Why it happens?

Thanks a lot,

Nava

EDIT: The crash happens in a runtime. The category file source resides in project B along with a SingletonClass

Comment: You mean a compiler crash or a runtime crash?, Where do you have your Category?, is it on project A or on project B?

Comment: runtime crash. The category is in project B where is the main class resides.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Category import strange behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099561/objective-c-category-import-strange-behavior)

Comment: I'm surprised your code even compiles.  The parentheses following "feature" in the implementation are superfluous.

Comment: @JeremyP the real code compiles. There was a typo in the question. Of course the code I brought here was only to demonstrate the problem, not the real piece of code, but the problem was solved. See my own answer on this.

Comment: @Nava Carmon: OK, I took the liberty of fixing the typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the -all_load and the -ObjC linker flags for your project.

Hope this helps,
Moszi

Comment: thank you, yesterday i put my own answer on this with a link to a similar SO question, which contains a link to apple's Technical Q&A with detailed explanation of the problem. btw, the flag is called -all_load or -force_load. Please fix your answer and I'll check it as a right one

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your category implementation isn't being compiled when you build project A. This sort of thing is definitely possible, Foundation/AppKit/UIKit make heavy use of categories to split large classes across multiple files.

You don't make it clear how your project B is included in project A. If it's a framework, shared or static library, then make sure your category file is included in the project B "compile sources" build phase. If it's included as source, make sure you compile that file as part of the project A build.

Comment: thank you for trying to help. I checked. Project B is a static library and the categories class is included in the compile sources build phase. Project A links agains the B static library, but sources from B are not included in a build phases of project A. I import the .h file of SingletonClass+MoreFeatures.h in a source file in project A when I want to use its functions.

Comment: @Nava so if you run `class-dump` on the static library, does it find your category? http://www.codethecode.com/projects/class-dump/

Comment: sounds like a great tool, but i cannot run it with this library for some reason. the library is a static .a library of arm6, arm7 architecture. trying to run ./class-dump libiProjectB.a gives a message: Input file (libiProjectB.a) is neither a Mach-O file nor a fat archive. But I ran a nm command on it and it sees SingletonObject(MoreFeatures) as a category of SingletonObject. I have exactly the same situation in project A (another singleton object with categories) and it works perfectly.